# Google Charts: Data label with suffix

Tags: charts, google-visualization, prefix, limesurvey, suffix

I am just starting with using google charts. I have a question. I would like to add data labels to my columns, in fact I have succeeded in this.  However, I would like to add a suffix to these labels (percentages %). I have tried to use NumberFormat, but then no chart appears. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script type="text/javascript">
   
  google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['corechart'] } );

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
  
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Kenmerk', 'Belangrijkheid', { role: 'style' } ],
        ['Uitstellen', 10, 'color: gray'],
        ['bijwerkingen', 20, 'color: yellow'],
        ['behandelingen', 30, 'color: red'],
        ['Schema', 40, 'color: blue']
      ]);


      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      // Set chart options

var options = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: 'Uitslag',
        vAxis:  { title: 'belangrijkheid van elk kenmerk in percentages uitgedrukt', format: '#\'%\'', maxValue: '100', minValue: '0'},
        legend: { position: 'none'},
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
              };

  
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
  </script></p>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;">
  </div>
```

Comment: Replace your calc function with one that does more than merely stringify.  Perhaps something like calc: function(dt, rowIndex) { return dt.getValue(rowIndex, 1).toString() + '%' }

Comment: This works! Thank you for your help!